# Traefik - Why getting connection refused error with ACME

Tags: docker, traefik

I am trying to setup a traefik proxy and and an nginx static website behind the proxy. Unfortunately I am not able to access the nginx website via https since I am running into issues with getting certificates via letsencrypt.

The traefik proxy will run with the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    container_name: 001-traefik
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=https"
      - "--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.https.http.tls.certResolver=le"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=email@email.de"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

After starting the nginx container I can find the following in the logs of the traefik container:

```
time="2023-01-10T11:32:02Z" level=debug msg="Adding route for site1.myserver.de with TLS options default" entryPointName=https
time="2023-01-10T11:32:02Z" level=debug msg="Trying to challenge certificate for domain [site1.myserver.de] found in HostSNI rule" rule="Host(`site1.myserver.de`)" routerName=https-nginx@docker providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
time="2023-01-10T11:32:02Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"site1.myserver.de\"]..." rule="Host(`site1.myserver.de`)" routerName=https-nginx@docker providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
time="2023-01-10T11:32:02Z" level=debug msg="Domains [\"site1.myserver.de\"] need ACME certificates generation for domains \"site1.myserver.de\"." providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" rule="Host(`site1.myserver.de`)" routerName=https-nginx@docker
time="2023-01-10T11:32:02Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [site1.myserver.de]..." routerName=https-nginx@docker providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" rule="Host(`site1.myserver.de`)"
time="2023-01-10T11:32:07Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"site1.myserver.de\""
time="2023-01-10T11:32:07Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:34672: remote error: tls: bad certificate"
time="2023-01-10T11:32:07Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..." providerName=le.acme
time="2023-01-10T11:32:07Z" level=debug msg="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" providerName=le.acme
time="2023-01-10T11:32:07Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"site1.myserver.de\": cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp:
lookup acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:55896->127.0.0.11:53: read: connection refused" rule="Host(`site1.myserver.de`)" routerName=https-nginx@docker providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
```

Any idea why I am getting this "connection refused" error message? There is no firewall or anything else blocking the traffic to this environment.